# MassTransit exchange creation

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit with RabbitMQ on a .net core 6 web application. My goal is to keep in sync several instances of an application, running on different plants. The application needs to be able to publish / consume messages.

When a site publishes something, this is broadcasted to all the sites queues (also itself, it will simply discard the message).

In order to do it, I configured MassTransit queue names with the suffix of the plant: eg norm-queue-CV, norm-queue-MB. I configured also the Consumer to bind to a generic fanout exchange name (norm-exchange).

Here my configuration extract:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {

            cfg.Host(new Uri(_configuration["RabbitMQ:URI"] + _configuration["RabbitMQ:VirtualHost"]), $"ENG {_configuration["Application:PlantID"]} Producer", h =>
            {
                h.Username(_configuration["RabbitMQ:UserName"]);
                h.Password(_configuration["RabbitMQ:Password"]);
            });

            cfg.Publish<NormCreated>(x =>
            {
                x.Durable = true;
                x.AutoDelete = false;
                x.ExchangeType = "fanout"; // default, allows any valid exchange type
            });
        }));
    });

    // consumer
    var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Host(new Uri(_configuration["RabbitMQ:URI"] + _configuration["RabbitMQ:VirtualHost"]), $"ENG {_configuration["Application:PlantID"]} Consumer", h =>
        {
            h.Username(_configuration["RabbitMQ:UserName"]);
            h.Password(_configuration["RabbitMQ:Password"]);

        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint($"norm-queue-{_configuration["Application:PlantID"]}", e =>
        {
            e.Consumer<NormConsumer>();
            e.UseConcurrencyLimit(1);
            e.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Intervals(100, 200, 500, 800, 1000));
            e.Bind<NormCreated>();
            e.Bind("norm-exchange");
        });
    });
    busControl.Start();
```

And here how NormConsumer is defined

```
public class NormConsumer : IConsumer<NormCreated>
{
    private readonly ILogger<NormConsumer>? logger;

    public NormConsumer()
    {

    }

    public NormConsumer(ILogger<NormConsumer> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<NormCreated> context)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Norm Submitted: {NormID}", context.Message.NormID);

        //await context.Publish<NormCreated>(new
        //{
        //    context.Message.OrderId
        //});
    }
}
```

Here the queues automatically created. To me they look fine
[image]

And here the exchange created. I was trying to get only one exchange (norm-exchange), but also the other 2 are created.
[image]

My problem is first of all understand if my layout makes sense (I'm quite new to Rabbit/Masstransit).

Moreover I'd like to override how exchanges are named, forcing to have for this queues only one exchange: "norm-exchange". I tried to override it in "producer" part, but not able to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ broker topology is covered extensively in [RabbitMQ - The Details](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cG2qzNgcsA), and also [in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/topology/rabbitmq.html#broker-topology).

You do not need to call `Bind` in the receive endpoint, consumer message types are already bound for you. Remove both `Bind` statements, and any published messages will be routed by type to the receive endpoints.